# Calling a jQuery function when a new element has been added to the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to call jquery function when a new element has been added to the DOM?

With jquery `.on()` I can do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("click", ".my-test", function() {
        console.log('New element added!');
    });
</script>
```

So when the element is clicked upon it'll write to the console - but can run this function as soon as it's added to the DOM?

I imagine it would look something like this..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* Just run when it's added... */
    $(document).on(".my-test", function() {
        console.log('New element added!');
    });
</script>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I think you are looking for "DOM change events": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-jquery-dom-change-listener